# create a grid of dots

Tags: android, android-view

I would like to create a grid of dots very much like in this game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nerdyoctopus.gamedots&hl=en

The aim is for each dot to be touchable, so I can recognise where that particular dot is and other information about it.

I don't really know where to start. Do I want to create a custom `View` for a dot with all the information I want, and then create multiple versions of it? And then do I arrange them in a grid with the `setTranslation()` method, or would it be better to use `LayoutParams` with offsets?

If I created my own "Dot" that extended "View", then I could add a lot of different information/methods to it - I could theoretically have a `changeColor()` method.  Is this the best way?

A `GridView` is not what I am thinking of (as far as I know) as it is basically a different style of `ListView`.

There are lots of questions here! I have looked at a number of questions here  on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but none show/ explain how I should start.

Comment: What is it about a GridView that makes it unsuitable for your needs?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I don't need it to behave like a list and be scrollable. I do need to be able to dynamically add another row or column and to the grid though.

Comment: Have you considered a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)? You could also subclass GridView and prevent it from scrolling.

Comment: are you saying that grid view is bad? Hey, but you can specify columns, every item can store imageview with tag storing information, right?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Is that more practical than creating a `View`s and positioning them manually in a grid?

Comment: Positioning them manually sounds like a lot of work, but it's really up to you. I suggest picking a method that makes sense to you and going with it. The same advice goes for the dot Views- you could make a custom View, or you could make a ShapeDrawable, or use a static image. Which one is "best" depends on your style and future needs.

Comment: @deadfish Not "bad", but not suitable - isn't it quite "expensive"? - I just need a grid of about 5x5 dots.

Comment: yup, but you do it dynamicaly instead declaring 25 elements and writting it like a monkey in xml layout. Think also about your project in future, what will happen if you decide you want not 5x5 but 7x7 ? Will you still be able add addiditional staic elements in xml layout? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for this. A GridView is the equivalent of a ListView in a 'grid' form, with scrolling, view recycling and whatnot, and that is not what you need. A GridLayout, as Dalmas suggested, would be a much better option if you want to build a static grid, but in my experience it is not easy to distribute the available space equally between columns, and if you are going to need to alter the grid distribution during the game, a TableLayout is much easier to use.

For the dots, yes, a custom view with a configurable color would be the best way to go around it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `GridLayout`. It will do exactly what you need. It is available through the android support library v7 : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout
It allows you to arrange views using a grid of rectangular cells.

For the dots, I would go with a custom dot view as you suggest, with a simple method to set the color. Don't store any data in the views if possible, it will make things much easier and flexible.

Comment: Would a `GridLayout` be better than a `GridView`?

Comment: Yes, a `GridLayout` is a lightweight container (like a `LinearLayout`) which displays views using a grid of rectangular cells. It has nothing to do with a `GridView`, which is designed to load data dynamically.

Comment: I think I will try a TableLayout as ivagarz suggested - mainly because he says it is simple to use. Thanks anyway :-)